# Is it gan3 ding3 she is saying in this sentence? Audio clip

Tags: audio

https://soundcloud.com/menevets/chinesepod-museum-clip

Around 3 seconds in, it sounds like gan3 ding3, but I can't figure out what it means. I think gan3 is 感. Could ding3 be 顶?

na4 wo3 men jiu4 gan3 ding2 xu4 yu4 zhe4 ge bu3 wu3 guan3 ma.

那我们就 [? ? ] [絮语?] 这个博物馆吗.

I'm pretty sure the gist of the sentence is now let's [something something] this musesum

Comment: It's 赶紧 (hurry up): 那我们就赶紧去这个博物馆吧.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

那我们就 **赶紧** 去这个博物馆吧！ （Nà wǒmen **gǎnjǐn** qù zhège bówùguǎn ba） - We should **quickly** go to the museum now.

赶 gǎn：to catch up; to overtake; to hurry; to rush; to drive away

紧 jǐn：tight; strict; close at hand; near; urgent; tense; hard up; short of money; to tighten

赶紧：hurriedly; without delay

Comment: 吧 fits the sentence much better, but she says it so fast, it sounds like ma. How do you tell the difference, it's so subtle.

Comment: @Steve You don't really even need to focus on that. You can tell from the context. `那我们赶紧就去...` sounds like a suggestion already so you can tell it's a 吧 (suggestive) and not a 吗 (question).

Comment: Not very important but the audio said '那我们*就*赶紧去这个博物馆吧'. 就 is missed in this answer.

Comment: @Steve 那 and 就 both suggest this sentence is affirming/echoing something said earlier instead of asking a question, so it must be 吧.

Comment: @NS.X. actually 就 is important. I heard it in the recording but forgot to type it. Thanks though

Comment: What @Steve mean is, I guess, 嘛, which is not so important, but very interesting to address that, and quite similar to 吧 too, both suggestive.